# Fitting a curve through scipy.optimize.curve_fit with endpoints fixed

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, endpoint, minimization

The following script fits a curve bowing-like via curve_fit (from scipy.optimize), see below:

```
ydata = numpy.array[ 1.6504   1.63928044  1.62855028  1.6181874   1.60817119 1.59848249   1.58910347  1.58001759  1.57120948  1.56266487  1.55437054  1.54631424   1.5384846   1.53087109  1.52346397  1.5162542   1.5092334   1.50239383   1.4957283   1.48923013  1.48289315  1.47671162  1.4706802   1.46479393  1.45904821  1.45343874  1.44796151  1.44261281  1.43738913  1.43228723  1.42730406  1.42243677  1.4176827   1.41303936  1.40850439  1.40407561  1.39975096  1.39552851  1.39140647  1.38738314  1.38345695  1.37962642  1.37589018  1.37224696  1.36869555  1.36523487  1.36186389  1.35858169  1.35538741  1.35228028  1.34925958  1.34632469  1.34347504  1.34071015  1.33802957  1.33543295  1.33291998  1.33049042  1.32814407  1.32588081  1.32370057  1.32160331  1.31958908  1.31765795  1.31581005  1.31404556  1.31236472  1.3107678   1.30925513  1.30782709  1.30648411  1.30522666  1.3040553   1.30297062  1.30197327  1.30106398  1.30024355  1.29951286  1.29887287  1.29832464  1.29786933  1.29750821  1.29724268  1.29707426  1.29700463  1.29703564  1.29716927  1.29740773  1.2977534   1.29820885  1.29877688  1.29946049  1.3002629   1.30118751  1.30223793  1.30341792  1.30473139  1.30618232  1.30777475  1.30951267  1.3114    ]

xdata = numpy.array[ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09 0.1   0.11 0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19  0.2   0.21  0.22  0.23  0.24  0.25  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.29  0.3   0.31  0.32  0.33  0.34  0.35  0.36  0.37  0.38  0.39  0.4   0.41  0.42  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  0.47  0.48  0.49  0.5   0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.55  0.56  0.57  0.58  0.59  0.6   0.61  0.62  0.63  0.64  0.65  0.66  0.67  0.68  0.69  0.7   0.71  0.72  0.73  0.74  0.75  0.76  0.77  0.78  0.79  0.8   0.81  0.82  0.83  0.84  0.85  0.86  0.87  0.88  0.89  0.9   0.91  0.92  0.93  0.94  0.95  0.96  0.97  0.98  0.99  1.  ]


sigma = np.ones(len(xdata))
sigma[[0, -1]] = 0.01


def function_cte(x, b):
     return 1.31*x + 1.57*(1-x) - b*x*(1-x)

def function_linear(x, c1, c2):
     return 1.31*x + 1.57*(1-x) - (c1+c2*x)*x*(1-x)

popt_cte, pcov_cte = curve_fit(function_cte, xdata, ydata, sigma=sigma)
popt_lin, pcov_lin = curve_fit(function_linear, xdata, ydata, sigma=sigma)
```

But I'm getting the plot in figure [image],

i.e., the initial points from both functions disagree with the data to fit (xdata, ydata).

I would like a fit constrained on the endpoints (0.0, 1.57) and (1.0, 1.31) at the same point that minimize the error. Any idea based on this code or it is better taking another way?

thanks!

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if your code could be run without editing.  Currently, the lines that create `xdata` and `ydata` are missing the commas that should separate the numbers.

Comment: The graph looks as if the fitted lines pass through those two constrained endpoints per the sigma array.

Comment: Warren, actually they are arrays. So, anyone would take it into account.
Btw, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Need the coefficients of function_cte, i.e. 1.31 and 1.57, to be fixed? If it isn' so, I'd recommend to formulate a constrained optimization problem. This only works if you got at least as much independent variables (in your case: unknown function coefficients) as equality constraints (in your case: constrained points)

Comment: Yes, Joni! The 1,31 and 1,57 have to be fixed, even that these constrains yield an increase of the error at the end of the minimization. See that into function_cte there is only one parameter to be optimized, i.e., "b", while into function_linear there are two (c1 and c2). It is expected that the function_linear provides a fit with lower error.

Comment: *"Warren, actually they are arrays. So, anyone would take it into account."*  Of course they are arrays.  That was not the point of my comment.  I was just giving some advice: you can help potential answerers of your question by making it easier to run your code.  You could edit the question and add the commas, or *everyone else* who wants to run the code will have to do that. Even better would be to ensure that the code is a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I tried to guess import statements and add commas to the "arrays" before I realized the point you made, that the code should edited to correct it.